Django create relation between this two tables from different db schemas
I use RDS. The db have different schemas for Users and Products
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "OPTIONS": {"options": "-c search_path=public"},
        "NAME": config("DB_NAME", default=""),
        "USER": config("DB_USER_NAME", default=""),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD", default=""),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST", default="db"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT", default=""),
    },
    "data": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "OPTIONS": {"options": "-c search_path=products"},
        "NAME": config("DB_NAME", default=""),
        "USER": config("DB_USER_NAME", default=""),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD", default=""),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST", default="db"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT", default=""),
    },
}

Can I create relation between this two tables from different db schemas?
Or only one decision move Product table to default db?
